# Hard drive problem after windows 7 install attempt?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, boot

My computer is an HP Media Center running Vista Home Premium. I has two separate hard drives each with 360GBs. I recently tried to install Windows 7 on the second drive but the installation failed. Despite saying it needed no input from me it went into a loop. I tried to uninstall it. I also had to change the Start Menu to 'Selective Start' because otherwise it tried to boot into Windows 7 and failed every time.
I now have only 235GBs on each drive. No clean up or reformatting of the second drive has any effect and no matter what clean up program I try I can not improve the capacity of the drives to the original specification.
I am not concerned so much about having lost 25GBs on both drives as to what is in the missing space. I plan to buy the final version of Windows 7 shortly and would prefer to clean up after the last failure. I still have to keep on 'Selective Start'. I will appreciate any help I can get.
JohnW

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use partition magic to increase the size of the partition or get rid of the Windows 7 partition. That way you would have a clean slate to start from.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a live CD partitioner, such as GParted LIVE CD to remove all partitions and erase all data on the hard drives, leave them blank (without any partitions), and then install Windows 7 again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rectify this using the built in Disk Management console within Windows.  See example screenshot below.

1. Right-click **Computer** and select **Manage**
2. Expand **Disk Management**
3. From there, you can visually see your partitions and you should have the option to expand partitions into empty space.

[image]

When you say selective start, are you referring to the menu asking which operating system you want to boot into, when you first switch on?  If so, take a look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/easily-set-default-os-in-a-windows-vista-and-xp-dual-boot-setup/) as it shows you how to fix this and set it back to just Vista.